# In the Dreamworld, why was Minato and Kushina like how they were when naruto first met them

Tags: naruto

In the Dreamworld, Naruto sees his mom and dad again. They both seem normal and like how we see them when they were sealing the nine-tails into  Naruto. WHy didn't their personalities change? Shikamaru turned dumb, Kiba became a cat lover so wouldn't that make Kushina have a gentler mom personality and Minato to be a terrible ninja?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description of Kiba being a cat lover, I am assuming you are referring to the [Road to Ninja movie](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Road_to_Ninja:_Naruto_the_Movie). While some characters do contain alternate personalities, not everybody's personalities changed in this world

> The majority of the movie takes place in an alternate dimension known as the Genjutsu World, where almost the entire cast has different personalities and behaviours compared to their actual selves. **Despite this, however, some still possess their own personalities and behaviours.**

This [Genjustu World](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Genjutsu_World) was created by Tobi's Limited Tsukuyomi in hopes to capture Kurama. While Minato's and Kushina's personalities did not change, their **roles** change with Sakura's parents

> The illusion is a prototype of the Infinite Tsukuyomi and was influenced by both Naruto's deep desire to have parents and Sakura's desire for freedom from parental control. Their desires, in turn, create a scenario where Minato Namikaze, who never became Fourth Hokage, and Kushina Uzumaki are alive and Sakura's parents, Kizashi and Mebuki Haruno, died defending the village